# How can i parse time difference as string like this

Tags: c#, string, parsing, datetime, datetime-format

I want to parse 2 DateTime difference like below:

```
312 Days 21 Hours 16 Minutes 5 Seconds // there is difference > days
21 Hours 16 Minutes 5 Seconds // there is difference > hours
16 Minutes 5 Seconds // there is difference > minutes
5 Seconds // there is difference < minutes
```

So if there are difference above days it will parse days if there are difference above hours it will parse hours and so on. If there are difference years I still want it to parse as days (days difference + (365*year))

Does C# have any function for this?

```
DateTime dt1
DateTime dt2

TimeSpan span = dt1- dt2;
```

And parsing TimeSpan as above (difference between 2 DateTimes)

Comment: What do you want from us? write it for you?

Comment: Why do you store a `TimeSpan` variable as such a string? Use a database!

Comment: @ColeJohnson Regex for what?

Comment: @L.B. Nevermind. I though he wanted to parse those strings into a DateTime. i.e. explode those numbers into an array using regex, then parse the numbers into a `DateTime`.

Comment: Do you mean you have the two `DateTime`, and you have subtracted them, but now you need a format string that will output the resulting `TimeSpan` in the way you indicate? Or is the string representation your input, and you want to create the `TimeSpan` value?

Comment: -1; You need to be a lot clearer on a couple things here friend. First, what exactly you're trying to do - parse the strings and do comparisons? Second, what have you tried already because in short, no C# doesn't have a function to parse and compare strings like that as `DateTime` objects.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG I think you use the verb **parse** incorrect.

Comment: @L.B you may be right. English is my secondary language :)

Comment: And after all that answers/upvotes/downvotes, the question is turned to be **`TimeSpan.ToCustomString()`** What a bad question....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something that might help:

```
string[] formats = {
  "d' Days 'h' Hours 'm' Minutes 's' Seconds'",
  "h' Hours 'm' Minutes 's' Seconds'",
  "m' Minutes 's' Seconds'",
  "s' Seconds'",
  "d' Days 'h' Hours 'm' Minutes'",
  "d' Days 'h' Hours 's' Seconds'",
  "d' Days 'm' Minutes 's' Seconds'",
  "h' Hours 'm' Minutes'",
  "h' Hours 's' Seconds'",
  };

var result = TimeSpan.ParseExact(yourString, formats, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

There's also `TryParseExact` if you fear `yourString` could occasionally be illegal. See [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) for details.

**Edit:** Asker has clarified that he did want "formatting", not "parsing", so my answer might not be relevant. Not sure what else is wrong with this answer.

Now, here's an (untested) solution. Zero parts are removed, not only when the most significant parts are zero, but also zero parts "in the middle" (`01:00:01`). Grammar (plural and singular) should be OK. Spaces ought to be correct in the midle and in the ends. Put into `static` class (extension method):

```
public static string ToMyString(this TimeSpan ts)
{
  if (ts < TimeSpan.Zero)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

  var parts = new List<string>();
  AddPart(parts, ts.Days, "Day");
  AddPart(parts, ts.Hours, "Hour");
  AddPart(parts, ts.Minutes, "Minute");
  AddPart(parts, ts.Seconds, "Second");

  if (parts.Count == 0)
    return "0";

  return string.Join(" ", parts);
}

static void AddPart(List<string> parts, int number, string name)
{
  if (number == 1)
    parts.Add("1 " + name);
  else if (number > 1)
    parts.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}s", number, name));        
}
```

Comment: Now there is something I've never seen before! Bravo!

Comment: Now there is something not working.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Have you really tried out my code? What happens?

Comment: but what is this yourString ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG This answer deals with "the wrong direction". It starts with the string, like `"312 Days 21 Hours 16 Minutes 5 Seconds"`, and finds the `TimeSpan` from that. I wasn't sure which direction you wanted.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen sure, your first sample gives FormatException

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Fixed (by moving the spaces to under the single quote marks `' ... '`).

Answer (score 2):

That was more difficult than expected:

```
List<string> timespanStrings = new List<string>() { 
    "312 Days 21 Hours 16 Minutes 5 Seconds", "21 Hours 16 Minutes 5 Seconds",
    "16 Minutes 5 Seconds", "5 Seconds"
};
List<TimeSpan> timespans = new List<TimeSpan>();
foreach (string tsString in timespanStrings)
{
    List<Tuple<int, string>> pairs = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
    var tokens = tsString.Split();
    if (tokens.Length % 2 == 0)
    {
        int duration;
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i += 2)
        {
            string dur = tokens[i];
            string unit = tokens[i + 1];
            if (int.TryParse(dur, out duration))
            {
                pairs.Add(Tuple.Create(duration, unit));
            }
            else // invalid string
                break;
        }
    }

    // create the TimeSpan from the pair
    switch (pairs.Count)
    {
        case 4:  // days
            {
                var dayPair = pairs.First(p => p.Item2.Equals("Days", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromDays(dayPair.Item1);
                var hourPair = pairs.First(p => p.Item2.Equals("Hours", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                TimeSpan tsHour = TimeSpan.FromHours(hourPair.Item1);
                var minPair = pairs.First(p => p.Item2.Equals("Minutes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                TimeSpan tsMin = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minPair.Item1);
                var secPair = pairs.First(p => p.Item2.Equals("Seconds", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                TimeSpan tsSec = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secPair.Item1);
                ts = ts + tsHour + tsMin + tsSec;
                timespans.Add(ts);
                break;
            }
        case 3:  // hours
            {
                var hourPair = pairs.First(p => p.Item2.Equals("Hours", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(hourPair.Item1);
                var minPair = pairs.First(p => p.Item2.Equals("Minutes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                TimeSpan tsMin = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minPair.Item1);
                var secPair = pairs.First(p => p.Item2.Equals("Seconds", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                TimeSpan tsSec = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secPair.Item1);
                ts = ts + tsMin + tsSec;
                timespans.Add(ts);
                break;
            }
        case 2:  // minutes
            {
                var minPair = pairs.First(p => p.Item2.Equals("Minutes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minPair.Item1);
                var secPair = pairs.First(p => p.Item2.Equals("Seconds", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                TimeSpan tsSec = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secPair.Item1);
                ts = ts + tsSec;
                timespans.Add(ts);
                break;
            }
        case 1:  // seconds
            timespans.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(pairs[0].Item1));
            break;
        default: 
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wants. My guess he only wants to format the TimeSpan. See the comment of  *Jeppe Stig Nielsen*

Comment: @L.B you are right. I want to parse TimeSpan :)

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: parsing TimeSpans means: take a string and create a `TimeSpan`. That's what my code does. Someone care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string ToFullString(this TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
    return
        (timeSpan.Days > 0 ? timeSpan.Days + " Days" : "") +
        (timeSpan.Hours > 0 ? " " + timeSpan.Hours + "Hours " : "") +
        (timeSpan.Minutes > 0 ? " " + timeSpan.Minutes + "Minutes " : "") +
        (timeSpan.Seconds > 0 ? " " + timeSpan.Seconds + "Seconds" : "");
}
```

Comment: @cole: dude, what up with editing all the posts? boredom?

Comment: i got nothing else to do

Comment: @David edits were correct (poor formatting both of code and output string). Also question was about parsing, not about converting to string.

Comment: Good effort. There could be some trouble with spaces. Also, I don't think the empty string is correct output if `timeSpan` is less than one second.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen you are right. If less than a second it should parse as 0. This function looks pretty useful expect need some more tuning if year > 0 convert it to days

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG No problems with `Days` greater than 365, because `TimeSpan` already disregards "years" and returns the total number of days (like `1000000` days).

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Shoud **"one hour and one second"** format as `"1 Hours 0 Minutes 1 Seconds"` or `"1 Hours 1 Seconds"`? Do you care about plural -s in the nouns?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen well that would be nice addition if s were correct. and i would prefer 1 Hour 1 Second. That is actually why i asked is tehre a built in function for that :)

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG I added a completely new solution to my answer that should handle singular number.

Answer (score 1):

If your inputs will be like:

```
312 Days 21 Hours 16 Minutes 5 Seconds
```

The answer will be no. You have to parse the string and initialize DateTime variables yourself. [Simple and clear DateTime tutorial for c#](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime).

After the initialization you can easily do substraction between those DateTimes. [Link for DateTime difference](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/DateDiff_CS_DC09132006172429PM/DateDiff_CS_DC.aspx).

If you want to print out the difference again with your previous style:

```
312 Days 21 Hours 16 Minutes 5 Seconds
```

It's easy to get Days, Month etc from the DateTimeDifference, for example:

```
DateTime yourDateTime = foo;
int month = yourDateTime.Month;
```